# Java SAX Parser, storing Attributes

Tags: java, xml, sax

I'm trying to store the current document position in a stack, pushing on startElement, popping on endElement. Right now I'm using:

```
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String elname,
                         String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
    original.append(innerText);
    original.append("<");
    original.append(elname);
    original.append(">");
    docStack.push(new StackElement(elname,atts));
....
```

Unfortunately when it tries to read the atts later, it gives error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attributes can only be used within the scope of startElement().

Is there any fast, reliable way to store the attributes?
Also, is there a better way to do this than constructing a new custom object StackElement for each start tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you push the Attributes onto your custom object stack, you are taking the actual Attributes object, which, according to the [documentation](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#startElement%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.Attributes%29) says this:

atts - the attributes attached to the element. If there are no attributes, it shall be an empty Attributes object. **The value of this object after startElement returns is undefined** (emphasis mine)

You should instead, in your startElement(...) method capture the attributes in a Map<String,String>.  This way you can use them where ever you want to.

Comment: It seems that would be a bit slow, constructing objects with every startElement, but even with this overhead, it should still be much more efficient than a DOM, correct?

Comment: It most definitely will be more efficient than a DOM, as you won't be storing everything, just some things.  I think your concerns about object creation are unfounded, as Java is not a slow and clunky language.  The memory and objects will be cleaned up once you are done parsing anyways.

Comment: This one can really bite you.  I had a document with 500M in it and it failed somewhere in the middle (after 10+ minutes of processing).  I was just caching the attributes object for use in the endElement function (as my model object needed the element text as well as the attributes).  It turns out that it works...  For a while...  Guess it is important to read the fine print.

Comment: Instead of a `Map` you could also use a `org.xml.sax.helpers.AttributesImpl` which has a constructor taking an `Attributes` object. The overhead would probably be similar.

Answer (score 4):

If `Attributes` is context sensitive, extract what you need from them in the `StackElement` constructor (and don't store the reference).

Something like this would do:

```
public class StackElement {

    private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public StackElement(String elname, Attributes atts) {

        for (int i = 0; i <  atts.getLength(); i++) {
            map.put(atts.getQName(i),atts.getValue(i));
        }
    }
}
```

p.s. It might seem like I plagiarised @nicholas's answer, but honestly, I had already typed it out and was working on the code when he posted.

Comment: I had thought of copying everything to a map like that, but I thought it would probably be inefficient, especially since I don't need ALL of the attributes on every element. That would be slower, since it's making TWO constructions of new class, constructing a new StackElement, and HashMap, AND querying all the attributes, on every element! My question is, is there any more efficient way to do this, maybe "freeze" the attributes and add to StackElement?

Comment: That getQName should be getLocalName